# Mysql Query Group By Display Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I want to display a table that looks like this from a Mysql query using PHP:

```
Vendor Name

Item Not to Drawing     Item Defective    Incorrect Item Received   Other

         9                    2                    3                  5


Vendor Name

Item Not to Drawing     Item Defective    Incorrect Item Received   Other

         2                    4                    5                  7
```

etc..

Here is my code....

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("qa", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Vendor, Sum(draw), Sum(defective), Sun(received), Sum(other) FROM qa_reports Group by Vendor Order by Vendor ASC");
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Item not to Drawing</th>
<th>Item Defective</th>
<th>Incorrect Item Received</th>
<th>Other</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Sum(draw)'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Sum(defective)'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Sum(received'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td'>" . $row['Sum(other)'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Not sure how to get the above results formatted as such.

I've done this with CFML but am new to PHP and can not grasp how to list results in a table grouped by a field.

Comment: can you please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: You have a typo in your query `Sun(received)`

Comment: What I am trying to do is list each vendor in the database and underneath them in a table the four fields that I have summed up. There are about 50 vendors so I want a report to list out Vendor one and the four fields summed out for vendor one, then vendor two etc...

Answer (score 2):

You need to alias your columns in order to reference them in your `$row` array.

```
SELECT vendor, 
       Sum(draw)      AS draw, 
       Sum(defective) AS defective, 
       Sun(received)  AS received, 
       Sum(other)     AS other 
FROM   qa_reports ...
```

Then you can reference them like so:

```
$row['draw'];
...
```

Comment: Thanks. The query works now. Now I just need to figure out how to properly format the displaying of the data.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT Vendor, Sum(draw) AS sumDraw, Sum(defective) AS sumDefective` ...

`$row['sumDraw']` etc.